# google spreadsheet - doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using `node v16.15.0` with the following libraries:

```
"google-auth-library": "^9.6.3",
"google-spreadsheet": "^4.1.1"
```

This is my function:

```
async function writeToSheet(data) {
    if (data.length === 0) {
        logger.info("No data to write to the sheet.");
        return;
    }

    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("sdfadsgsdfgadsfDML-17jbHMdXkgcqWtmvJ0");
    const creds = require('../credentials.json'); // Ensure the path to your credentials file is correct

    try {
        // Authenticate using the service account credentials
        await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
            client_email: creds.client_email,
            private_key: creds.private_key,
        });

        await doc.loadInfo(); // Loads document properties and worksheets
        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // Access the first sheet

        // Batch adding rows to avoid hitting rate limits for large datasets
        await sheet.addRows(data); // Adds multiple rows at once if 'data' is an array of objects
        logger.info("Data successfully written to the sheet.");
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error("Failed to write data to the sheet:", error);
    }
}
```

However I get this error:

```
"TypeError: doc.useServiceAccountAuth is not a function\n    at writeToSheet (/home/writeToSheet.js:60:19)\n    at /home/writeToSheet.js:126:15\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)"
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

From your versions of `"google-auth-library": "^9.6.3"` and `"google-spreadsheet": "^4.1.1"`, in your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
import { GoogleSpreadsheet } from "google-spreadsheet";
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library";

async function writeToSheet(data) {
  if (data.length === 0) {
    logger.info("No data to write to the sheet.");
    return;
  }

  const serviceAccountAuth = new JWT({
    email: creds.client_email,
    key: creds.private_key,
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
  });

  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(
    "sdfadsgsdfgadsfDML-17jbHMdXkgcqWtmvJ0",
    serviceAccountAuth
  );

  try {
    await doc.loadInfo(); // Loads document properties and worksheets
    const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // Access the first sheet

    // Batch adding rows to avoid hitting rate limits for large datasets
    await sheet.addRows(data); // Adds multiple rows at once if 'data' is an array of objects
    console.info("Data successfully written to the sheet.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to write data to the sheet:", error);
  }
}

const sampleData = [
  ["a1", "b1", "c1"],
  ["a2", "b2", "c2"],
];
writeToSheet(sampleData);
```

- When your service account can write the Spreadsheet `"sdfadsgsdfgadsfDML-17jbHMdXkgcqWtmvJ0"`, the sample data can be appended to the 1st sheet of the Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet)